# Visual Studio 2019 MFC C++ Make button open another dialog box?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

I have a Dialog-based MFC app, and it has two Dialog Boxes:

1. `IDD_FITNESSAPP_LOGIN_DLG`
2. `IDD_FITNESSAPP_MAIN_DLG`

On `IDD_FITNESSAPP_LOGIN_DLG`, I have a button, `btnLogin`, that runs through some credentials (working so far, and reports failures too).

How do I make it so that when I click `btnLogin` on `IDD_FITNESSAPP_LOGIN_DLG`, it leads to `IDD_FITNESSAPP_MAIN_DLG`?

I read a little on `Dlg.DoModal()` but I don't understand that if its needed.

Here's the code for the "on button clicked `btnLogin`":

```
void CFitnessAppMFC2Dlg::OnBnClickedbtnlogin()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    UpdateData();

    char UsernameFromFile[20], PasswordFromFile[20];
    FILE* fleCredentials;
    bool ValidLogin = false;

    if (m_Username == "")
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("You must provide a username and a password or click Cancel"));
        return;
    }
    if (m_Password == "")
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Invalid Login"));
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Open the file for reading
        fleCredentials = fopen("credentials.txt", "r");

        // Scan the file from beginning to end
        while (!feof(fleCredentials))
        {
            // Read a username
            fscanf(fleCredentials, "%s", UsernameFromFile);

            // Compare the typed username with the username from the file
            CT2A ascii(m_Username);
            if (strcmp(ascii, UsernameFromFile) == 0)
            {
                // With the current username, retrieve the corresponding password
                fscanf(fleCredentials, "%s", PasswordFromFile);

                // Compare the typed password with the one on file
                CT2A ascii2(m_Password);
                if (strcmp(ascii2, PasswordFromFile) == 0)
                {
                    ValidLogin = true;
                }
                else
                    ValidLogin = false;
            }
        }
        if (ValidLogin == true)
            OnOK();
        else
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Invalid Credentials. Please try again"));
            this->m_EditUsername.SetFocus();
        }

        fclose(fleCredentials);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Could not validate the credentials"));
    }

    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: Yes, `DoModal()` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1.`Resourse View-> Dialog->Right click->Add Resource->Dlg`, Then add class for the new Dlg.

2.There are two types of Dlgs.

### Modal Dialogue Box

When the user wants to operate on applications other than the dialog box, the dialog box must first be responded to.

```
 #include "CXXXDlg.h "

 void CXXXDlg::OnBnClickedOk() 
 {   
     CMyNewDlg  Dlg;   
     Dlg.DoModal(); 
 }
```

### Modeless Dialogue Box

When the user opens a non-modal dialog box, other windows can still be operated.

```
#include "CXXXDlg.h"

void CXXXDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    CMyNewDlg  *pDlg=new CMyNewDlg ;
    pDlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG2,this);
    pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```